# TFS 2017 Failed to move widgets

Tags: tfs, widget, dashboard

We are running TFS 2017 Update 2 (on-premise).

When I want to move some widgets on a dashboard I sometimes, but not always, get this error message after moving one widget: 
"Failed to move widgets. Changes have been made to the dashboard by another user. Refresh the page and try again."

I am pretty sure that I am the only user editing the dashboards in question.

The tedious workaround I use to move forward is:

1. Click Edit Dashboard
2. Move one widget once
3. Refresh the browser

Repeat steps 1-3 for as many widgets I want to move. The same happens if I try to delete widgets. I can add multiple widgets just fine for some reason.

I have experienced this across two different TFS installations. Right now our third installation does not do this. All three installations are running TFS 2017 Update 2.

I have tried from two different pcs using both Chrome and IE with same results.

Does anyone know what causes this error and what we can do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the items below:

1. Upgrade TFS 2017.2 to the latest edtion TFS 2017.3.1.
2. Try InPrivate Browsing in IE or incognito window in Chrome
3. Try to Press F12 to check whether there is useful information when the issue occurs.

Comment: Hi Cece. I've looked at your three suggestions. #1 is in the backlog so it will happen eventually. #2 did not change anything - the same error occurs. #3 perhaps gave a bit more as I can see this: "Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vHMu9W_H19ZO_Am-VJjuKtgKblidS4MH5FJpFq-VZ2JY=:36 TFS.WebApi.Exception: Exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Dashboards.WebApi.WidgetETagConflictException' was thrown." Does this give any new clues?

Comment: I can also see this: 
"PUT (URL to our TFS)/68a2e710-21e8-44b3-ab08-4cfe8736d497/49a53ebc-0fbb-4ee5-9c21-276dd52b951b/_apis/Dashboard/dashboards/b613b15c-8445-45a4-aa7a-f3682a73b464/Widgets 409 (Conflict)"

Comment: Is it possible that it's caused by network latency? Are you able to try the same operation on VSTS?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in VSTS. It just works there - as expected. :) It could be latency on-premise and today I only experience the error on one of the two installations in question. Any clues as to where we should look for latency - between application tier and database or other places?

Comment: Sorry that I'm not familiar with network. But you would ask your IT team to test the network on both application tier machine and data tier machine.